# Solving system of delay differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, delay-differential-equations

Are there any numerical methods for solving systems of delay differential equations with time-dependent delays?
For example, I have a system:

$$\frac{dP_1}{dt}  = f_1(t) P_2(t-\tau(t)) P_3(t)$$

$$\frac{dP_2}{dt}  = f_2(t) P_3(t-\tau(t)) P_1(t)$$

$$\frac{dP_3}{dt}  = f_3(t) P_1(t-\tau(t)) P_2(t)$$

I thought about applying method of steps together with Runge-Kutta method, but it leads to loss of information, because Runge-Kutta method requires values of RHS at $(x+1/2 h)$, where $h$ is a step.

So, I'm interested if any other methods except this one exist for solving such systems.
And, if they exist, could you please tell me where I can read about them, because I didn't find useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ddeint package](https://github.com/Zulko/ddeint).

Some further explanation can be found [here](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/10/22/delay-differential-equations-in-python/).

> It is not very fast, but very flexible, and coded in just a few lines on top of Scipy’s differential equations solver, odeint.

Comment: None of the two links point out to a reference with the algorithm or the method they are using. But the person who asked the question is actually asking for the method and not a software/package.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the paper "*Solving ODEs and DDEs with Residual Control*" from Shampine for using Runge-Kutta for your DDE (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apnum.2004.07.003). Matlab has already a command `ddesd` for solving DDEs with non-constant delay terms with this paper as its reference. You can watch this short video on how to use this Matlab command (https://youtu.be/s3G1aCCE-4Q). But it doesn't talk about the algorithm, so you still have to read the cited paper.

I think you need to give an explicit example of the functions $f_i(t)$, $i=1,2,3$, $P_i$s $i=1,2,3$ and $\tau(t)$ that is giving you what you call "loss of information". Here is an example which I tried with Matlab and it didn't raise any error or warning.

```
sol = ddesd( @ddefun, @delay, @history, [ 0, pi ] );
t = sol.x;
p = sol.y;
plot( t, p( 1, : ), 'r', t, p( 2, : ), 'g', t, p( 3, : ), 'b' );
xlabel( 't' );
ylabel( 'P(t)' );

% local functions
function dxdt = ddefun( t, x, Z )
    dxdt = [ ( t + 1 ) * Z( 2, 1 ) * x(3); ( t ^ 2 + 1 ) * Z( 3, 1 ) * x(1); (cos( t ) ) * Z( 1, 1 ) * x(2) ];
end
function d = delay( t, x )
    d = t - cos( t );
end
function v = history( t )
    v = [ 1; t + 1; 1 - t ^ 2 ];
end
```

And here is the figure generated by Matlab.

[image]